# Webpack tree shaking still bundles unused exports

Tags: typescript, webpack, bundler, tree-shaking

I am trying to test out Webpack's tree shaking feature, but it does not appear to be working.

Here are my files:

- `index.ts`

```
import { good } from './exports';
console.log(good);
```

- `exports.ts`

```
export const good = 'good';
export const secret = 'iamasecret';
```

- `tsconfig.json`

```
{}
```

- `webpack.config.ts`

```
import { Configuration } from 'webpack';
import  * as TerserPlugin from "terser-webpack-plugin";
const config: Configuration = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './index.ts',
    module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            use: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
          },
        ],
      },
      resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ]
      },
      optimization: {
        usedExports: true,
        minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()],
      }
}
export default config;
```

- `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "webpacktest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/terser-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/webpack": "^4.41.11",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.5",
    "ts-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.8.2",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
    "webpack": "^4.42.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
  "sideEffects": false
}
```

When I run `npx webpack` it bundles the files into `dist/main.js`. When I open that file, the secret string is in there despite it being an unused export. Is there a way that I can stop it from being included in the final bundle?

Comment: Why is your "tsconfig.json" empty? Webpack is able to tree-shake such imports if your ts is transpiled into es modules.

Comment: FYI: The point is that [the default value of `target` is `ES3`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target), so your result is apparently NOT using ESM import syntax, and thus cannot be tree-shaken.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out. I needed to install the packages `@babel/core`, `@babel/preset-env`, and `babel-loader` as dev-dependencies, and change my Webpack config rule for handling TypeScript files to:

```
    {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: ['babel-loader','ts-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
    },
```

Next, I created a `.babelrc` file with the following content:

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "modules": false
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Finally, I changed/added the following lines to my `tsconfig.json` under `compilerOptions`:

```
"module": "es6",
"moduleResolution": "node",
```

Using `babel-loader`, setting the `.babelrc` config, and using `"module": "es6"`, allowed for my TypeScript code to be tree-shaken. `"moduleResolution": "node"` fixed an issue where I was getting errors that certain modules could not be resolved.

Comment: `babel-loader` is not required. It works the same with `ts-loader` only.